# Plugin not found when importing project as library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-library

I am trying to integrate an application to another one. To do that I compiled the first one as a library and after that I added it to the dependencies of the application project after I added it as a module following some guides in stackoverflow.

The problem is that after doing that, I got an error about a missing plugin. Although I have researched a bit over google I have had no luck on that one.

The error is **Error:(4, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.protobuf' not found.
Open File**

Both applications work very well, each on their own...  What am I doing wrong ?

**Here is my build graddle of the main app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.arlind.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

}
```

**Here is the build graddle of the added library**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-alpha-3'
}
}

android {

signingConfigs {
    global {
        keyAlias "Lind"
        keyPassword "gators"
        storeFile file("lindkey.keystore")
        storePassword "gators"
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.global
    }
}

productFlavors {
    catapult {

        versionCode getLongDate().toInteger()
        versionName '12.1-' + getShortDate()
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-2'
    compile project(path: ':wallpaperPicker')

}

sourceSets {

    main {
        manifest.srcFile '../AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['../src', '../util', '../extra/src']
        res.srcDirs = ['../res', '../extra/res']
        proto {
            srcDir '../protos'
        }
    }

}
}

def getDate(String dateFormat) {
def df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat)
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
df.setTimeZone(tz)
return df.format(new Date())
}

def getLongDate() {
return getDate("yyMMddHH")
}

def getShortDate() {
return getDate("yyMMdd")
}
```

Comment: I know I'm a bit late but try to add `compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.7'` to your dependencies block